Почему при добавлении overflow-y-hidden так же скрывается горизонтальная часть
В стилях добавил только overflow-y: hidden, но почему-то вместе с этим скрывается и горизонтальная часть. overflow-x: visible не помогает

Потому, что overflow-y: hidden автоматически переводит overflow-x в значение avto.


В стилях добавил только overflow-y: hidden, но почему-то вместе с этим скрывается и горизонтальная часть. overflow-x: visible не помогает

Предложу такое решение...


section {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  /* вот это добавить */
  overflow-y: clip;
}
div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>



Но у clip есть свои особенности. На русском описание не нашел... :(
Вот на английском https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/11/11/overflow-clip-and-overflow-clip-margin-properties/
